# "Latest activity" with a background color on Super User

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

On other sites, the "latest activity" is a simple link, written the same way as the two previous informations.

On Super User, however, this link has a blue background (which makes it finally quite "flashy").

Any reason for this difference, or is it simply a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The latest activity is now linked, so on large questions you can just click it to go to where the "action" was.

(similar to the way it's [linked on the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/add-link-to-most-recent-activity-of-a-question))